# How do Savepoints work in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, migration, rollback

I'm doing pretty serious operations on my DB and I would like to keep my data safe.

Unfortunately something is going wrong, look:

```
SAVEPOINT before_foo_update;

CREATE TABLE AUX_FOO as
   SELECT * FROM FOO;

TRUNCATE TABLE FOO;  

ALTER TABLE FOO
  MODIFY(BAR NUMBER(11) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO FOO
  SELECT * FROM AUX_FOO;

DROP TABLE AUX_FOO;    

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT before_foo_update;
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error:

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT before_foo_update
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01086: savepoint 'BEFORE_FOO_UPDATE' never established
01086. 00000 -  "savepoint '%s' never established"
*Cause:    Trying to roll back to a save point that was never established
```

Now FOO table is empty...
And AUX_FOO wasn't dropped.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A savepoint is a point within the current transaction.  A `DDL` statement like `CREATE TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `ALTER TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` will issue an implicit commit before and after the statement runs that will end the current transaction.  Once the current transaction ends, you can no longer rollback to a savepoint defined within that transaction.

Potentially, you want to look at using a [restore point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/rpfbdb002.htm) instead.  A restore point is an attribute of a database, not a transaction, so you can generate many transactions and still restore the entire database back to the restore point.  Restoring to a restore point, however, will affect every change that had been made to the database between the time that you defined the restore point and the time that you do restore-- you would lose all changes made not just by your session or your user but all sessions and users in the database.

Comment: OK, I see. So is there any possibility to roll back from table creation, truncation, modifications but not affecting other users?

Comment: Restore points and FLASHBACK probably are the best way to roll back to a database state before DDL statements have been executed. Please note, however, that you need the Enterprise Edition of Oracle Database to use FLASHBACK; this feature is not available in the standard edition. See edition comparison here: http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/product-editions-066501.html .